# How can i predict the decay modes and branching ratios of the phi-meson (mass 1020 MeV)?

Tags: particle-physics, mesons

I have looked up the pdg and found different decay modes in which three of them are the most occurring in nature. They are $\rm\phi\rightarrow K^+K^-$, $\rm\phi\rightarrow K_0\bar K_0$, and $\rm\phi\rightarrow \pi^+\pi^-\pi_0$. How can I calculate each decay width and the total decay with to calculate the branching ratios?

Comment: The generic dynamical law *suppressing* the 3 *π* mode out of the $s\bar s$  comprising the *φ* led Zweig in 1964 to postulate quarks, and is now called the OZI rule: basically that the strange q's are reluctant to annihilate themselves in favor of gluons, which then produce pions. As @ Chris points out, this is best quantified through nonperturbative techniques. If the rule worked perfectly, *all* decay modes would consist of Ks.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81746/what-is-the-precise-statement-of-the-ozi-rule).

Answer (score 1):

*You* don't, really. At the very least, you need a supercomputer to do the number crunching for you.

Strong decays (i.e. those involving QCD) in general have to be computed non-perturbatively. This means there is no way to get an analytic result, and you can't just compute a few diagrams and get a result that's reasonably close like you can with weak and electromagnetic decays.

QCD quantities can be computed non-perturbatively in some cases using a supercomputer. See [lattice QCD](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0506036), for instance. These computations are very computationally demanding, and the results typically have a large uncertainty at the end.

Comment: Hi Chris, what you write is true, but particularly for larger energies, the coupling constant $\alpha_S$ becomes sufficiently small that perturbative theory is applied to QCD.

Comment: @MathIsFun The structure of hadrons, and thus the computation of strong decays, is firmly outside the regime of perturbative QCD.

Comment: Anyway it should be doable, atleast very approximately. I just found this exact question in Halzen-Martin pg 49.